# How I can change the highlight color of a TEdit component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I need to tweak the appareance of a TEdit component, But i'm failing to find a solution to change the highlight color and font color of a TEdit component when the text is selected (highlighted) , exist any WinApi  message or function to change the highlight color?

Comment: I believe the answer is 'no'.

Comment: How wedded to themes are you?

Comment: In XE3 FM2: Edit1.SelectionFill.Color := claYellow

Comment: `TEdit` uses the Windows color definitions that Delphi nicely names `clHighlight` and `clHighlightText` (and the VCL retrieves from the global Windows settings for you). The only way to change those in `TEdit` is to change them globally for all Windows applications. @slotomo: That's only for the FMX `TEdit`, not for the standard VCL (Windows) `TEdit`. Since the poster has tagged this `delphi-2007`, I don't think what's possible in XE3 applies anyway. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I expect that those colors are only used in non-themed controls.

Comment: @David: And therefore the colors used would be the theme equivalents. The point? It's a global setting unless you custom draw the control yourself. :-) Well, at least until you've upgraded to a version of Delphi that supports VCL themes, which D2007 doesn't.

Comment: @Ken In non-themed controls you typically can change the colors without having to paint the entire thing. That's not the case for themed controls.

Comment: @David: OK. Change the highlight color in a normal TEdit without doing anything to paint it. Oh, right - you can't, because there's no Windows message  (`EM_`) for doing so, and the VCL doesn't expose a property that allows it either (maybe for that reason). There's no `OnCustomDraw` event either. It's a global system color setting, just like when themed controls are drawn. That's why there's no syntax coloring available for the standard `TMemo` either, which is simply an `EDIT` control with the multi-line style set.

Comment: @David: According to MSDN, edit controls do not support [custom draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Ken It's a notification message, WM_CTLCOLOREDIT. But I don't think there's anything for highlight color.

Answer (score -1):

Drawing of component is done inside `WM_PAINT` message. In `WndProc` you should set the desired color to `clHighlightText` before call of standard `WndProc` and reset it to default after call. I think this is the simplest solution.

Comment: From what you're writing, *"set the desired color to clHighlightText"*, what is that desired color and how would you set it in the `WM_PAINT` message handler ? Could you include a code example, please ? Or you wanted to suggest to change the system color of the `clHighlightText` during a `WM_PAINT` stage of the control ? I think, that would lead to an infinite loop (due to a `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` sent to the control, which would ask the control to invalidate again).

Comment: You can block `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` message during your `WM_PAINT` handler. It was just an idea, I dont have code for it now.

Comment: Well, so your idea was to call `SetSysColors` from inside the `WM_PAINT` message handler. Note that doing so will broadcast the `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` message, and even if you prevent its processing in your subclassed edit control, the other controls will suffer on processing this message. I'm just trying to tell, that it's a bad idea in my view. [not voting]